# WPF - ListView scroll like movie credits

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem, autoscroll

I have a simple ListView with a `ControlTemplate` on its `ListViewItem`. The situation is like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>                
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <!-- Some values with bindings -->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Now, all elements are ready when I launch my program. I would be able to scroll this items automatically with an animation, like credits of a cinema movie, from its top to the last item.

This is not an "autoscroller" when adding an item: I will not add nothing to this list. I Just want to make it going slowly from top to down.

I don't want to use a simple textbox / textblock 'cos it's too raw for me.

Any ideas? I found nothing about this type of "autoscroll" of a `ListView`.

Comment: Put your text in your favourite control and then animate the transform

Comment: No... I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old post may be helpful:
https://dlaa.me/blog/post/9857745

Comment: This could be the solution... I'll try to get it work even if it's old

Answer (score 1):

Catch the Loaded Event on the ListView, Drill down using VisualTreeHelper to get the ScrollViewer.

Then, use its methods to scroll down using some DispatcherTimer.